# Plugin Development: extending a vendor plugin

Tags: plugin-development, extends, classes

I'm using composer to import a third-party (vendor) plugin into my own Craft plugin. But can't figure out how I extend the functionality of the imported (vendor) plugin.

For example assuming imported plugin defines a base class of `XXX` I can try to extend this with `class YYY extends \XXX` but not sure where I save this so I can access this in my code, eg I want to extend the base plugin through a class, eg

```
class YYY extends \XXX
{
    public function doThis($str) { return $str; }
}
```

I'd then want to access this in my Craft plugin with

```
$var = new \XXX();
$var->doThis = 'CONTENT HERE';
```

Obviously grossly simplified but hope you get the gist.
Just can't figure out how to achieve above or where I should save the code that is extending the vendor class?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, if you do this:

```
$var = new \XXX();
$var->doThis = 'CONTENT HERE';
```

Then `doThis` will never exist for class `\XXX` because `\XXX` isn't where the method was defined.  It would work from your extended class, though:

```
$var = new YYY();
$var->doThis = 'CONTENT HERE';
```

Keep in mind that (usually) if the vendor plugin instantiates any instances of that class internally, it will always be of instance `\XXX`, not your `YYY` class.

Where that wouldn't be true, is if the vendor plugin supports [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) where they allow you to inject your extended `YYY` class wherever `\XXX` would usually be referenced.

Comment: Thanks Brad - makes sense but still a bit confused about how to achieve this. To provide more detail I am creating a plugin that utilises the FPDI library through composer but want to extend the core functionality with some custom methods and not sure how best to achieve this. 

Hayelp!